# Is there a program to graphically edit the values of the Embedded Controller in an Acer laptop?

Tags: acer, overheating, fan

Sorry if this already has an answer, but no matter how unspecific my searches get I can't seem to find anything.

My Acer Aspire 5740G has horrible overheating problems. I have taken the computer completely apart and cleaned everything, so please don't suggest that.
In Windows, I was able to put my fan speed to full by using the tool, RWEverything. It let me edit the values of my EC; a guide I eventually found told me what to edit.

After a while, Windows just got too slow, so I switched to Ubuntu. It worked at first, but my overheating and crashing problems returned, this time with no fan control. So, what I need is an EC or ACPI table editor that will let me control my fan speed. RWEverything in Wine doesn't even run, and I've already tried `lm-sensors`, which doesn't work.

Does anyone know of something that can do this? Sorry for any vagueness (feel free to ask for clarification) or nonsense here. I'm a little distracted.

Comment: Their portable version is not an option?

Comment: @Rinzwind No, Neither opens.